# docker login not responding

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, tcp

My `docker login` is not responding . It is stuck as shown below

```
$ sudo docker login ghcr.io -u user --password-stdin
```

We have disabled egress in our environment except for few ports which includes `443/80` .

Does `docker login` uses other port than 443/80 ?

Just to add we are running docker in a `compute engine` instance on `GCP` environment

Comment: try to review this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry#authenticating-to-the-container-registry)

Comment: I would suggest to enable debug in docker configuration, then restart the service or send HUP signal to the main process and then observe logs, it could be a network issue...